# Load Balancer does't load some sites

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, css, tp-link

I have a TP-Link Load Balancer TL-R480T+ and I use two Wan connections that go for an intern server that makes the DHCP server, etc.

But the problem is that here I use two sites that when I try to log in don't load the CSS file and return the error `NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED` and `NS_ERROR_CORRUPTED_CONTENT`.
This problem only occurs when the two Wans are connected in the Balancer. If I use only the first Wan the sites work normally.

I thought it was something about the DNS configuration, but I changed them and it keeps with the same error, the sites only work if I use only the first Wan.

Am I losing some configuration in the Balancer? It can block only CSS from some sites?